# Find the smallest positive integer divisible by 63 such that the sum of its digits is also divisible by 63.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

TASK: Find the smallest positive integer divisible by 63 such that the sum of its digits is also divisible by 63.

MY WORK: Let the number be $A=\overline{x_n x_{n-1} x_{n-2} \cdots x_1 x_0}$.    Since $63|(x_n+x_{n-1}+\cdots+x_1+x_0)$, we have that $x_n+x_{n-1}+\cdots+x_0\ge63\cdots(*)$ and since $x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are n+1 digits, we have that 
$x_n+x_{n-1}+\cdots+x_0\le9+9+\cdots+9=9(n+1)$ which then means that
$9(n+1)\ge63\Leftrightarrow n+1\ge7$ i.e that the number $A$ has at least seven digits. If it has $7$ digits, all of them would have to be $9$ to satisfy the inequality $(*)$ which would mean that $A=9999999$. But then the condition $63|A$ would not be satisfied. So the number A doesn't have seven digits - it has at least eight digits.

However, I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: So check numbers like 18999999 and 19899999 and 19989999 and so on.

Comment: You get divisibility by $9$ for free so you only need be concerned about checking for $7$

Answer (score 9):

Assume the the number is $1$ with 6 $9$s and one $8$.

Now $19999999\equiv 5\pmod 7$

If we subtract $10^k $ we will get aus a number with a $1$ , 6$9$ and one $8$ anda different equivalence.  so we need to find the $10^k\equiv 5\mod 7$.

$10\equiv 3$

$100\equiv 30\equiv 2$

$1000\equiv 20\equiv 6$

$10,000\equiv 60\equiv 4$

$100,000 \equiv 40\equiv 5$

So $19,999,999-100,000=19,899,999\equiv 0\pmod 7$.

And that's that.  It's digits add to $63$ so it's divisible by $9$ and it's divisible by $7$.  And beginning with $1$ and the only such divisible by $7$ it's the smallest such number.

====

I thought I made it clear why this is the smallest.

No element with $7$  digits or fewer exist as the OP figured out.  For a group with $8$ digits the smallest would start with a $1$.  If you have an $8$ digit number beginning with $1$ and whose digits add to $63$ the remaining digits must be six $9$s and one $8$.  Such a number can be written as $19,999,999 - 10^k$ where $0\le k \le 7$.  For such a number to be divisible by $63$ we must have $10^k \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.  The *ONLY* such $k$ is $k = 5$ and $10^k =100,000$ and the number is $19,899,999$.  So this is the only such number divisible by $63$ whose digits add to $63$ in the smallest possible category of types of numbers that can have such numbers.  So this is the smallest such number.

Comment: Is that the smallest such number? [no criticism of your answer intended... but OP originally asked for smallest.] (+1 on answer.)

Comment: Sorry @coffeemath , I had a typo.

Comment: Yes, it's the smallest. And I explained why. There can't be one with 7 digits, so the smallest has eight or more.  This has 8 so it is in the smallest group.  the smallest digit it can begin with is 1 so this is the smallest of the smallest.  If number starts with 1 and has 8 digits and adds to $63$ then is must have 6 nines and one 8.   So smallest number would be $19,999,999 - 10^k$ where $10^k\equiv 5 \mod 7$.  The *only* such option for $0\le k \le 7$ is $k=5$.  So this is the only solution with 8 digits begining with $1$.  And no smaller number is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

(This is essentially the same solution as @fleablood 's; but doubts were raised whether it is actually the smallest.)

Such a number has at least $8$ digits. Since the prescribed digit sum is $63$ we have to deduct exactly $9$ units from writing eight nines. Trying with $x_1=1$ as first digit, and all other nines, we have given away $8$ units, one more to go. Divisibility by $9$ is taken care of automatically. Now $19\,999\,999=5$ mod $7$; therefore we need to find a $k\in[0..6]$ with $10^k=5$ mod $7$, or we are bust with $x_1=1$. Fortunately $10^5=5$ mod $7$. It follows that $19\,899\,999$ is the smallest number with the required properties.

Comment: @coffeemath: Sorry for the typo. Thank you for reporting it.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest number whose digits all sum to a multiple of $63$ is $9{,}999{,}999$. The next smallest is $18{,}999{,}999$, then $19{,}899{,}999$, then $19,989{,}999$, and so on.  All of these are clearly divisible by $9$, so it suffices to check for divisibility by $7$. As it happens, the first two are not, but $19{,}899{,}999/7=2{,}842{,}857$ (and, just to doublecheck, $19{,}899{,}999/63=315{,}873$).

Remark: It's not *a priori* obvious that any of the numbers described here will turn out to be divisible by $7$. You could say we just got lucky. Or you could do a modular argument to show that luck had nothing to do with it. One thing is obvious: the smallest number sought for is certainly no greater than $777{,}777{,}777$.

Comment: The modular argument is not hard.  The numbers are all of the form $19,999,999 - 10^k$ so we need $19,999,999 - 10^k \equiv 0 \mod 7$ or $10^k \equiv 5 \mod 7$.  As $10$ and $7$ is relativley prime and $7$ is prime the $10^k; 0\le k < 7$ are distinct modulo $7$ and $10^5$ is the only one that works.

Comment: @fleablood, are you saying, more generally, that if $10$ and $p$ are relatively prime (with $p$ a prime), then $10^k$ for $0\le k\lt p$ are distinct modulo $p$? It's true that $10$ is a primitive root mod $7$, but not because it's relatively prime to $7$.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I worded it incorrectly.  $10\equiv 3$ is a primitive root is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

I also verify that the Number 19,899,999 is the smallest number that is divisible by 63 and Also its sum is divisible by 63.
Here a program I wrote in Python 3. To find this out by brute forcing :

```
for i in range(9999990, 19900000, 63):
     sum_is = sum(int(d) for d in str(i))
     if sum_is%63==0:
             print(i)

Prints : 
19899999
```

Also this time I started from 9999990 because this number the last number divisible by 63 that has sum less than 63.

**This can also be used to do the same with any number.**

Just change the range and 63 as you want.

Hope this Helps!

**[EDIT SUMMARY]**
For more Optimization and better Understanding. Added direct summing instead of sum_digits as request/suggested by **@Paul Evans**. Also added jump of 63 as Suggested by **@Kyle Kanos**.

Comment: Instead of the mysterious `sum_digits(i)` you could write python code: `sum(int(d) for d in str(i))`

Comment: You can also save time by starting at 9999990 and incrementing by 63, eliminating the need to test i%63==0.

Comment: Yes! That's more optimized. Thanx for advice.